# zsh: command not found: laravel can't find command

Tags: laravel

I install laravel using the following code
 `composer global require "laravel/installer"`
then I run
 `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"`
to put this in my path, but what I got is
zsh: command not found: laravel
what can I do now?

Comment: ```export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` to the beginning or the end of your ~/.zshrc file

Then run `source ~/.zshrc` on your terminal or restart your session